# Translation of "sniff"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Suppose I'm in the library studying.  One of the couple of dozen people there sniffs every 132 seconds instead of blowing his nose.  When I look around it's impossible to identify the source of the sniffing.  This is one of the things that bother me the most about not being a hermit.

How can I talk about this horrible habit of sniffing in Spanish?  I've never found a good way.

Comment: **Sorber:** 2. tr. Atraer hacia dentro la mucosidad nasal.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence you're looking for is "**sorber los mocos**":

> **[sorber](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=sorber)**.
>
> Del lat. *sorbēre*.
>
> 2. tr. Atraer hacia dentro la mucosidad nasal.

Although it may appear that just saying "sorber" would suffice, I think **it's better to be specific and say "sorber los mocos"** (unless the context is very, very clear), because the first meaning of "sorber" is "to drink from a straw".

Comment: Gracias por responder tú. En inglés me expreso muy mal

Comment: @blonfu - Sí, como dijo walen.  El español es mi segundo idioma y actualmente vivo en EEUU.  A veces por flojera pongo una pregunta en inglés pero si me das una respuesta en español te voy a entender.  (O si incluyes alguna palabra o expresión que no conozco, te diré.)